# What symbols can be loaded using `spl_autoload_register()`?

Tags: php

I know that `spl_autoload_register()` can be used to dynamically load class definitions.
However, I've also seen people autoloading interface definitions, and even traits.

The [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) only mentions autoloading classes, it has no hint that missing interfaces or traits are also autoloaded. So, I wonder if there are other symbols that can be loaded using an autoloader.

Some samples:

```php
$a = new MyApp\Admin\Users()
// → The "Users" class inside can be autoloaded on demand.

class Users implements IBase {}
// → The IBase interface can be autoloaded.

class Users {
    use SomeTrait;
    // → The trait can be autoloaded.
}

// What other cases are there? For example:

$res = admin_user_find('admin');
// Can I use an autoloader to load "includes/admin-user-find.php"
// when admin_user_find() is undefined?

if ( SOME_FLAG ) { }
// Can I use an autoloader to load "consts/default-some-flag.php"
// when the constant is undefined?
```

TL;DR: What kind of symbols or definitions can be loaded using a `spl_autoload_register()` handler?

Comment: Please do not put multiple questions into a single question

Comment: You could set your auto load to look up 1) a list of files with functions to include, or 2) put every function in one file names with the function name. _(Never seen one of those. I would suggest using OOP only.)_

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "autoload undefined functions or constants"? From where should they get loaded?

Comment: @NicoHaase Autoloading functions and constants is a perfectly reasonable idea - they'd be load from whatever file you wanted, just like classes are; a reasonable structure would be one file per namespace, but that would be entirely up to the user, just as you can have multiple classes in one file. It's a feature that the language maintainers would really _like_ to add, but there are unfortunate interactions with decisions made many years ago when namespaces were added.

Comment: I have voted to re-open, because I think this is a perfectly reasonable question, and the two numbered questions are really just different ways of wording the same thing: "What can be autoloaded?"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: And using something that doesn't resolve with the autoloader does not automatically throw an exception: https://3v4l.org/uWOdk

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that autoloading is currently available (as of PHP 8.1) for:

- classes
- interfaces
- traits

The documentation - both the [introduction to autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and [the function reference for `spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) could definitely be clearer on this point. Feel free to [suggest an edit](http://doc.php.net/tutorial/).

---

As a bit of background, the reason these three types of symbol are all included is that they share the same *symbol table* - you cannot have a class called "Foo" *and* a separate interface called "Foo" or trait called "Foo".  Note that namespaces don't change this - you can have a class called "Some\Name\Space\Foo" and a trait called "Another\Name\Space\Foo", but they don't have the same *full* name, and within any piece of code, "Foo" can only be shorthand for one or the other.

For classes and interfaces, there's a very good reason for this, because they are often used in the same places; for instance:

```php
if ( $someObject instanceof Foo ) {
    echo 'The object is a Foo';
}
```

This can be true *either* because `Foo` is the name of a class, and `$someObject` is an instance of that class or a sub-class; *or* because `Foo` is the name of an interface, and `$someObject` implements that interface.

Traits are included more for convenience - I can't think of any places where it's ambiguous whether a name refers to a class or a trait, but having them share a symbol table generally feels more helpful than separating them. One of the reasons it's helpful is that we essentially got trait autoloading "for free", using the mechanism which already existed.

---

Meanwhile, there are a few reasons why functions and constants *can't* be autoloaded, beyond "nobody got round to doing it yet":

- Since they *don't* share a symbol table with classes, the autoload callback would need to be told which it's looking for. That is, you *can* have a function called "foo", a class called "foo", *and* a constant called "foo"; loading the class definition when PHP was looking for a function wouldn't be very helpful.
- When autoloading was added (in PHP 5.0), the language didn't yet have namespaces. A class containing static methods and class constants was therefore the best way to logically group a set of functions; for those, class autoloading was all you needed.
- When namespaces *were* added (in PHP 5.3), a decision was made which was useful in the short term, but probably a mistake in the long-term: functions and constants resolve namespaces *differently* from classes and interfaces. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
namespace My\Name\Space;
$object = new Foo;
$length = strlen('hello');
```

The PHP compiler always expands the class name "Foo" to "My\Name\Space\Foo". At run-time, if the class doesn't yet exist when the line is executed, the autoload function is triggered with that name, and if it still doesn't exist after that, you get an error.

The function name "strlen", however, can refer *at run-time* to either "My\Name\Space\strlen", or if that doesn't exist, to the built-in global function "strlen". That makes it easy to use built-in functions, but it's not obvious when the run-time would call the autoload function. There have been a few suggestions, but none has yet made it beyond discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces and traits are parts of classes. You can only autoload classes and so on. If you want to autoload functions then let it be a part of a class.
Here an Example for a static class:

```
class myClass {
   public static function myFunction() {
       echo "works";
   }
}

myClass::myFunction();
```